# Why form.is_valid() does not returns false immediately when the first clean_<field_name> raises ValidationError?

Tags: django, validation, django-forms

I have defined a form with two `CharField`. I have defined clean method for both fields.  In my view I am calling the `is_valid()` method of the form I defined. I am giving an invalid input for `field1` so that `clean_field1` method raises `ValidationError`.

In `clean_field2` I am accessing `cleaned_data[field1]`. When calling the url, it is giving 500 error. And in stack trace it says **KeyError: 'field1'**. On debugging I found `ValidationError` was raised in `clean_field1` method.

I expected that `Form.is_valid()` will return false when `clean_field1` raised `ValidationError`. But django went on to execute `clean_field2`. Why django is executing `clean_field2`, when `clean_field1` raised `ValidationError`. `form.is_valid()` should have returned `False` when `clean_field1` raised `ValidationError`. Am I correct?

Does `form.is_valid()` method return only after executing all `clean_<'field_name'>` methods(even if `ValidationError` was raised)? If yes, then this poor design I think. If first `clean_<'field_name'>` method raises `ValidationError` then what is the point in executing other `clean_<'field_name'>` method? I think `Form.is_valid()` should return `False` when it encounters first `ValidationError`. Or am I missing something?

It will be really helpful if anyone can explain what is going on? Thank you.

The code that I was executing:

```
class MyForm(Form):
    field1 = forms.CharField()
    field2 = forms.CharField()
    def clean_field1(self):
        clean_field1 = self.cleaned_data['field1']
        if not check_validity(clean_field1):
            raise ValidationError(_('Invalid Field1 input'), code='invalid_field1_input')
        return clean_field1

    def clean_field2(self):
        clean_field2 = self.cleaned_data['field2']
        my_query_set = MyTable.objects.filter(my_field__exact=self.cleaned_data['field1'])
        if not my_query_set.exists():
            raise ValidationError(_('Some Error'), code='some_error_code')
        return clean_field2

class MyView(View):
    def post(self, request):
        response_data={'status':'fail'}
        json_data = json.loads(request.body)
        form = MyForm(json_data)
        if(form.is_valid()):
            #do something
            response_data['status']='success'
        else:
            response_data['errors']=form.errors
        return JsonResponse(response_data)
```

Comment: Your `clean_field2` method uses the data from multiple fields, `field1` and `field2`. Therefore this code belongs in the `clean()` method. See the docs on [validating fields that rely on each other](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other) for more information.

Comment: @Alasdair thank you for the reply. I think there should be an option to allow is_valid to return false as soon as any of the clean_<FieldName> raises an error. Check my comments on Daniel's answer. What are your thoughts?

Comment: I think that the current behaviour is the correct choice for most users. I'm not sure that your example where validating fields is time/resource consuming is very common, so I'm not sure that it justifies adding an option. If you want to change the behaviour of your form, you could try subclassing [`_clean_fields`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/a92cc84b4a206d18a5f1a0eaa47f19add40ff99b/django/forms/forms.py#L378) and make it exit early when there's a validation error.

Comment: If you're serious about adding it as an option to Django, you could suggest it on the [django-developers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/) mailing list. As a first step, it might be better to release a `FastFailingForm` outside of Django. If it had lots of users, that would make the argument for adding it to Django stronger.

Comment: @Alasdair Yes a FastFailingForm outside of Django is better way to get it done. Thank you for your idea. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django validates all fields prior to determining the validity of the form as a whole.

This is both intentional and a smart design. The reason is it is infuriationg to be a user and fill out a form and not recieve complete feedback on your submission.

For example, if you had a field with 10 fields and the user entered 4 incorrect values, it would be a pain to have to submit the form 4 times. Each time the form is submitted a new field is discovered to be invalid.

This is exausting for the user. Because of this Django validates all inputs.

You can read about the validation flow in the [Djanog Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/validation/) Read the paragraph just above the "Raising ValidationError" header.

Comment: Thank you for replying. You are right it will be frustrating. I think there should be an option  to allow is_valid to returns false as soon as any of the clean_<FieldName> raises an error. Suppose client uploads 10 encrypted files. You have to verify file header before proceeding further. Current behaviour will be inefficient. One of Django design philosophy is "Explicit is better than implicit". Just my thoughts. I may be wrong. What is your thought on this use case? And I really appreciate you for taking the time to answer my question.